# url is loaded in browser instead of WebView in android

Tags: android, webview, runtime, android-linearlayout

I want to create a linearLayout,a WebView on runtime without having any xml in my android project and load a url in webView.

I have declared a webView :

```
WebView web =new WebView(this);
```

I have added a linearLayout :

```
LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
        view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Then I added a webView to it :

```
web.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.addView(web);
```

Now i LOAD THE URL :

```
web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");





         web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override 
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false; 
                } 
            });
```

But then nothing happens.

**If I dont set webViewClient then url is loaded in browser instead of webView**.
**I just want to load the url in webView. Please help.**

Comment: then what is your question?

Comment: just  `return true;`  instead of  `return false;`

Comment: first set client then load url!

Comment: i have returned true but the result is same... @MD

Comment: first setting client and then loading url didnt work too... already tried.

Comment: I just want to load the url in webView not in browser...Here browser is being launched from the application. @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use WebVideClient, here is an easy example:

```
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}


    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
}
```

Comment: When i use setWebViewClient ..  its not even launching the webView. So above code is not working. If I simply load the url using web.loadurl("https//:google.com") then its opening url in device browser.. not in webView.

Answer (score 0):

i had something similar to your problem what i ended up doing is setting up the WebViewClient in a nicer way

```
public WebView web;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webpage_detail, container, false);

        web = ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webpage_detail));
        web.loadUrl(mItem.url);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        return rootView;
}

  public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
```

just take a look at the webViewClient code this worked for me . also setting would recommend `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
since most websites require javascript to run on mobile views e.g Twitter